# how to download torrents via UDP links in Torrent Trackers

Tags: bittorrent, udp

Let's say you were searching for something on a torrent site, and instead of the usual `.torrent` file or a `magnet link`, you were presented with the image below:

[image: list of UDP links and Torrent Trackers]

What would you do next to download the torrent?

I'm new to `UDP` links and "Torrent Trackers" and need a **tutorial** on how to use them.

(In case it matters, my bitTorrent client is PicoTorrent, and it has features for downloading only `.torrent` files or `magnet links`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not download links. This table is just *part* of the information you'd normally find *in* the `.torrent` file, or in the Magnet link.

The purpose of trackers is only to *track* which other peers have the same torrent, often alongside another method called DHT ("trackerless"). However, you still need to know *what to ask them for.*

The main identifier of a BitTorrent download is the "hash" or "infohash", usually shown as 40 hexadecimal digits (although your screenshot is missing two of them) or 32 Base32 digits.

Knowing it, you can create a Magnet link that most programs will recognize, using just the `xt=urn:btih:<INFOHASH>` parameter. (Note that most clients require the infohash to be converted from hex to Base32.)

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:A1B2C3...
```

With this, your client will be able to download the remaining information (first the .torrent file, then the actual data) using DHT. You can also specify a list of trackers as `tr=<URL>` parameters, for example:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:abcdef...&tr=http://example.com/announce&tr=udp://example.net:1234/announce&tr=...
```

(As in many HTTP URLs, the parameters start after `?` and are separated by `&`'s.)